# Building Boost For Android with arm64_v8a using GCC

Tags: c++, gcc, boost, android-ndk, arm64

I am trying to build the Boost library for arm64 support with NDK 17c using GCC (We haven't moved to clang).

Here are the user.config.jam:

```
# ----------------------
# Android configuration.
# ----------------------

using gcc : androidR8
:
$ANDROID_NDK_ROOT/toolchains/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-g++
:
<archiver>arm-linux-androideabi-ar
<compileflags>-fexceptions
<compileflags>-frtti
<compileflags>-fpic
<compileflags>-ffunction-sections
<compileflags>-funwind-tables
<compileflags>-D__ARM_ARCH_5__
<compileflags>-D__ARM_ARCH_5T__
<compileflags>-D__ARM_ARCH_5E__
<compileflags>-D__ARM_ARCH_5TE__
<compileflags>-Wno-psabi
<compileflags>-march=armv5te
<compileflags>-mtune=xscale
<compileflags>-msoft-float
<compileflags>-mthumb
<compileflags>-Os
<compileflags>-fomit-frame-pointer
<compileflags>-fno-strict-aliasing
<compileflags>-finline-limit=64
<compileflags>-I${ANDROID_NDK_ROOT}/platforms/android-26/arch-arm/usr/include
<compileflags>-Wa,--noexecstack
<compileflags>-DANDROID
<compileflags>-D__ANDROID__
<compileflags>-DNDEBUG
<compileflags>-O2
<compileflags>-g
<compileflags>-I${ANDROID_NDK_ROOT}/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.9/include
<compileflags>-I${ANDROID_NDK_ROOT}/sysroot/usr/include
<compileflags>-I${ANDROID_NDK_ROOT}/sysroot/usr/include/arm-linux-androideabi/
<compileflags>-I${ANDROID_NDK_ROOT}/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.9/libs/arm64-v8a/include
# @Moss - Above are the 'official' android flags
<address-model>64
<architecture>arm
<compileflags>-fvisibility=hidden
<compileflags>-fvisibility-inlines-hidden
<compileflags>-fdata-sections
<cxxflags>-D__arm__
<cxxflags>-D_REENTRANT
<cxxflags>-D_GLIBCXX__PTHREADS
;
```

As shown, I have set:

```
<compileflags>-I${ANDROID_NDK_ROOT}/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.9/libs/arm64-v8a/include

<address-model>64

to build for arm64_v8a. Still, the generated binary objdumps:

objdump -D libboost_atomic-gcc-mt-1_62.a

libboost_atomic-gcc-mt-1_62.a(lockpool.o):  file format ELF32-arm-little
```

Here is my bjam command:

```
cmd="env PATH=$(dirname $CXXPATH):$PATH \
        AndroidNDKRoot=$(GetNDK) NO_BZIP2=1 \
        ./bjam toolset=$TOOLSET -q \
            cxxflags=\"$CXXFLAGS\" \
            link=static threading=multi --layout=versioned install";

TOOLSET=gcc-androidR8
CXXFLAGS=-fPIC
CXXPATH=android-ndk/toolchains/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-g++
```

It builds fine for armeabi-v7a.

How to make Boost to generate arm64 libraries with gcc?

Comment: You need to go through everything architecture-specific and make sure that it's set correctly for am arm64 build. For example, shouldn't your `CXXPATH` lead to `aarch64-linux-android-g++`? And all those `ARM_ARCH_5` flags and `-march=armv5te` should be changed, since that's not the architecture you're building for.

Comment: @Micheal Thanks, it worked after I used the aarch64 toolchain.